# How do you insert a page break into a RDLC report?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, report, rdlc

This is a very simple thing, but I just haven't been able to find anything. I have a report and at the end, I have a "totals" row.  I simply want to insert a page break before this row so that it prints on a separate page.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the [MSDN page on how to set page breaks in a report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251733%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

The page states that:

> Item page breaks apply only to the report items rectangle, table,
>   matrix, list, and chart.

So I think to put the row total control on it's own Rectangle that is added after the Tablix, but does not overlap with the Tablix. Then specify in the Rectangle properties that it should have a page break *before it*.

I also found this link that explains how to force a page break after a specific row, which may help if your total is part of the Tablix:

[Page break after Specific rows in rdlc reporting](http://yeasir007.blogspot.com/2012/10/page-break-after-specific-rows-in-rdlc.html)